# Value from one script to another c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make a lives counter in unity with c# so i made a ui text in unity with the value Livesvalue = 3; in a other script i have the deatchscene so when i die the value goes to the other script en does -1 but i get an eroor that the value does not exist

UItext code:

```
 public class livesscript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static int Livesvalue = 3;
        Text Lives;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            Lives = GetComponent<Text>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            Lives.text = "Lives: " + Livesvalue;
        }
    }
```

deathscene code:

```
    private void StartDeathSequence()
    {
        state = State.Dead;
        audioSource.Stop();
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(death);
        deathpart.Play();
        mainEnginepart.Stop();
        livesscript.Livesvalue -= 1;
        Invoke("RespawnLevel", Waitdead); // parameterise time
        LivesRespawn();
    }

    private void LivesRespawn()
    {
        if (Livesvalue == 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `LivesValue` is static so you need `if (livescript.Livesvalue == 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing a static variable you need to include the class name and a period before the variable.

```
private void LivesRespawn()
{
    if (Livesvalue == 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

change to

```
private void LivesRespawn()
{
    if (livesscript.Livesvalue < 1)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```